# Save the Best time in Level Selection scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, scene

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKBww.png)I want to save the best time meaning the lowest amount of time taken to complete a level in the game. When I try to do that the timer begins from the start in the Level Selection screen. What I want to do exactly is save the time taken to complete the level and store that amount of time in the level selection scene. If the time taken to complete the level is less when we replay the level, that amount of time shows instead of the first. I have looked for about 2 Days and couldn't find a solution.

I tried to do it but when I load the level selection screen the timer starts from 0. I even tried to make bools such that when the game starts it is set to true but still it doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do here;

Do you want to save the best time on persistent storage (PlayerPrefs or a save system) or just for the current scene (score is lost as soon as the scene unloads)?

I assume this is only a timer script; you need a method to save the score on level end (but only if the current score is lower than the already present value) and maybe another script to visualize it on the level selection screen, as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but I found a way to store it by using PlayerPrefs.